# JupyterHub Helm chart ingress path giving a 404 not found when used with ingress-nginx controller

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, jupyterhub

I am using two Helm charts, one for [JupyterHub](https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/blob/main/jupyterhub/values.yaml#L514) and one for the [Ingress-Nginx controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml). I am attempting to have path based rules set in my JupyterHub ingress objects to have the controller route to individual namespaces.

In the JupyterHub Helm chart I am able to enable an ingress object in the same namespace that the JupyterHub environment is provisioning into. I am also able to set a pathSuffix in the ingress object, for instance `/namespace1`, which I can see with a `kubectl describe ingress -n namespace1`.

If I attempt to access either the root URL or URL with a path I am sent to a `404 Not Found nginx` error.

If I do not have a pathSuffix set on the ingress object then I am able to access the root URL but I am assuming I go to a random namespace.

This is the full output of `kubectl describe ingress -n namespace1`

```
Rules:
  Host                       Path  Backends
  ----                       ----  --------
  <NAME>.com
                             /namespace1   proxy-public:80 (11.1.1.29:8000)
Annotations:                 kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                                     meta.helm.sh/release-name: jupyterhub
                                     meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: namespace1
```

I do not have any additional annotations enabled on my ingress object and the only thing set on my ingress-controller is the LoadBalancer IP.

Am I missing something additional like annotations or a YAML config value for the controller?

The only additional thing I can think of is that there is a proxy service which can be set as a LoadBalancer IP but I set that to a ClusterIP. This is due to using an ingress controller and I did not want an external IP set there. Does this need to be a NodePort?

```
kubectl get svc -n namespace1

NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
hub            ClusterIP   11.2.0.140   <none>        8081/TCP   101m
proxy-api      ClusterIP   11.2.0.119   <none>        8001/TCP   101m
proxy-public   ClusterIP   11.2.0.148   <none>        80/TCP     101m
```

```
proxy:
  secretToken:
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: Can you access the jhub without the ingress?

Comment: @Matt Yes I'm able to access without enabling ingress but to do this I need to set a value within the configuration YAML for the Helm chart to set the proxy as a LoadBalancer and give it an IP address. But doing this will not allow me to dictate which namespace a user will end up in.

Comment: Could you try to set [hub.baseUrl](https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/blob/main/jupyterhub/values.yaml#L40) to match ingress path?

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I had someone suggest that yesterday on the JH forums and haven't had a chance to try it out until today. I tried that initially and it did not work so what I did was just set the hub.baseUrl to `/namespace1` without any quotes and that worked. I'm able to access website.com/namespace1 and website.com/namespace2. If I start up an environment with different username logins in each I can run `kubectl get events -n` and see each namespace spin up pods with different usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set the `hub.baseUrl` to `/namespace1` [in values.yaml file](https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/blob/main/jupyterhub/values.yaml#L40) of jypyterhub helmchart.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing I do not use the helm chart to deploy jupyterlab